# How to keep receiving values if an inner Observable fails in a stream of Observable of Observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm in this situation, I have an Observable of Observables like this:

```
 public outerFunction(
    collections: someObject
  ): Observable<someOtherObject> {

    const outerObservable$ = new Observable<Observable<someOtherObject>>(
      (observer) => {

        const collKeys = Object.keys(collections);
        for (const id of collKeys) {
          if (collections[id]) {
            const innerObs$ = this.functionThatReturnsObs(
              collections[id]
            )
            observer.next(innerObs$);
          }
        }
      }
    );
    return outerObservable$.pipe(mergeAll(1));
}
```

The `functionThatReturnsObs` makes an Http call to retrieve some data,

My problem is that; if one of the calls fail I don't get any other data from the others http calls, as if the stream was interrupted.

I would like to do something like:

```
this.outerFunction(collections).piep(
map((data) => /* do something with this data*/),
catchError((error) => /* in case of failure of one of the http calls do something */ ));
```

**UPDATE**

Calling `observer.next(innerObs$.pipe(() => empty());` seems to not work for me,

but I manged to have the desired behavior by returning the  `Observable<Observable<someOtherObject>>` from the `outerFunction` and then using `mergeMap` like this:

```
  public outerFunction(
    collections: someObject
  ):Observable<Observable<someOtherObject>> {

    const outerObservable$ = new Observable<Observable<someOtherObject>>(
      (observer) => {

        const collKeys = Object.keys(collections);
        for (const id of collKeys) {
          if (collections[id]) {
            const innerObs$ = this.functionThatReturnsObs(
              collections[id]
            )
            observer.next(innerObs$);
          }

        }
      }
    );
      return outerObservable$;
}
```

and then:

```
this.outerFunction(collections).pipe(
mergeMap((innerObs$) => innerObs$.pipe(
map((data) => /* do something with this data*/),
catchError((err) => /* in case of err handle the faild HTTP call */)
)),
);
```

But I don't know why it works this way, can someone explain why?

Comment: https://medium.com/@erVikas1/how-to-keep-an-observable-returned-by-httpclient-alive-after-error-da6c5e601e9c

Answer (score 3):

You already had the right idea of using `catchError`. To prevent the outer observable from dying, just add it to the inner observables. For example

```
observer.next(innerObs$.pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY)));
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately it doesn't prevent the outer Observable from dying. I updated my question because I found a solution but I don't understand why it works this way